# OBJC @selector doesnt work from another implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
int alert()
{
    //Alerting
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"0%" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50.0F, 50.0F)];
    
    UIButton *sampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [sampleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,60.0F, 40.0F)];
    [sampleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage systemImageNamed:@"terminal.fill"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [sampleButton addTarget:[[MyObject alloc] init] action:@selector(showTerminal) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    
    [customView addSubview:sampleButton];

    [alert.view addSubview:customView];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}

@implementation MyObject

-(void)showTerminal
{
    NSLog(@"Terminal opened!");
}

@end
```

How can I make @selector work when calling function from another @implementation!

I have tried this code but the function never executes "[sampleButton addTarget:[[MyObject alloc] init] action:@selector(showTerminal) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];"

Can someone help me fix it or tell me a work around that doesn't involve using the ViewController()?

Comment: BTW: handlers commonly set on `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addTarget` is not retaining, so yours object is deallocated. You can use class object and method to retrieve event

```
[sampleButton addTarget:[MyObject class] action:@selector(showTerminal) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

and:

```
+ (void)showTerminal
```